# Retrieving databases from phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was working on cakephp and used phpmyadmin for my cakephp project.  I have moved to another machine and I forget to take a dump of my sql file. But took the whole phpmyadmin folder. Is it possible to make it work to get back all my databases?

I am not able to login with that phpmyadmin and in my new machine I have my own phpmyadmin.

Please give me some suggestions.

EDIT

**WIll it be possible to get back the databases from my cakephp project .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is only an interface for the MySQL server and as such does not store the database within it's folder structure.

To recover the database your best bet would be to try and get a backup of the old machine and extract the database from the backup.

Comment: --Will it be possible to get databases from my cakephp project

Comment: no, once again the cakePHP project will just store the information about where and how to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin just contacts your database. No information (except for the ip-adress (servername)) is present in your directory copy.

You can't get your databases back from the phpmyadmin-directory copy.